# How to avoid dead zone in Generative adversarial?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

During training the two network, the generator converge slowly but suddenly it enter dead zone where all output is zero.

I believe this problem is due to learning rate and fast convergence in the discriminator part which force the generator to output zeros everywhere and can't find the best solution.

I reduced the learning for both of them and tried different implementation but every time I achieve 2000 epochs or higher I enter into dead zone.

Any advice from GAN experts/users ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [it is about machine learning rather than software development](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291009/1233251). You can ask these questions on [Cross Validated](//stats.stackexchange.com) or [DataScience.SE](//datascience.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I checked the link you add on your comment, could you tell me where could we post these general questions related to deep learning ? btw giving me negative doesn't help my profile in order just to say this is not related question

Answer (score 0):

It is natural for GAN to die - how soon would it happen, depends from your particular problem. GAN is doomed to die due to the fact, that the point when discriminator is satisfied can never be reached by definition. That means: you are ending up with oscillations (gen "power" >> disc) or mode collapse (gen << disc).

1. Try several technics, from my experience the best/easiest known approach is weight norm + prelu
2. Try to make your disc weaker (smaller state, dropout, smoothing categories, skipping training, everything reasonable you can imagine is fine)
3. Again, here I have to promote a paper about stochastic deconvolutions were are going to publish soon. It is a simple trick that improves stability very much. Details here: [Training GAN on small dataset of images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48601991/training-gan-on-small-dataset-of-images/48607379#48607379)